# SQL: Select multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a bit of a problem. I have a table with names, IDs and different geometry like so:

```
ID  |  Name| RealID| Geometry| 
==========================================
1   |      Hampshire     |   3   |  0762453...
2   |      Hampshire     |   3   |  0156245...
3   |      Salt Lake     |   2   |  312455...
4   |      Hampshire     |   3   |  016422....
```

I have a need of selecting all Hampshire rows based on a list of IDs. As you can see my table has different geometries for say Hampshire.
I need all of them somehow by just comparing against one ID I get from a list of them.

I get the list of IDs from Java. It is simply a list with one ID(3) so far.

Doing this:

```
Select * from table where RealID = any(:listOfIds)
```

It only returns me one row no matter what if I send in Hampshire's ID in the list (3). I have tried something like this:

```
Select * from table where RealID IN (any(:listofids))
```

but the syntax is wrong and I'm not sure what to do to achieve my goal.

Comment: `:listOfIds` is not a valid JDBC placeholder. Please show us your Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following syntax

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE RealID in (listOfIDs)
```

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE RealID in (3,2,6....)
```

You can try this also:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', RealID);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I now I have all Hampshires and can do what I want with them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make some thing secure and clean code you can use this way :

```
String query = "Select * from table where RealID IN (";

for (int i = 0; i < list.lenght(); i++) {
    query += (i == 0 ? "" : ", ") + "?";
}
query += ")";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
for (int i = 0; i < list.lenght(); i++) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(i, list.get(i));
}
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    //get your informations here
}
```

You should to loop throw your list and use PreparedStatement so your query should look like this :

```
Select * from table where RealID IN(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is safe way.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one .

```
 Select * from problem where RealID IN (?,?,?);
```

? =here put on RealID according your requirement 
 ex:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE RealID in (3);
```